iOS SwiftUI - How to place markers on images like google maps
Hi I am working on a iOS version of a project I did for Android and I am trying to place markers/annotations on an image. I was able to get some help for the android version but I don't really understand the math and how to do the same in SwiftUI.
Right now this is what I have setup in Swift -
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct ImageView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = viewModel()
    let index: Int
    @State var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State var show: Bool = false
    @State var currentAnnotationSelected: SelectedAnnotationModel?
    @State var showDialog: Bool = false
    @State var note: String = ""
    @State var localY: CGFloat = 0
    @State var globalY: CGFloat = 0
    @State var localX: CGFloat = 0
    @State var globalX: CGFloat = 0
    var annotationIndex: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            KFImage.url(URL(string: viewModel.uri ?? ""))
                .placeholder {ProgressView()}
                .loadDiskFileSynchronously()
                .cacheMemoryOnly()
                .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local).onEnded { dragGesture in
                 self.localY = dragGesture.location.y
                 self.localX = dragGesture.location.x
                 showSheet = true
              })
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            VStack {
                AnnotationNote(x: Int(self.localX), y: Int(self.localY))
            }
            .presentationDetents([.medium])
            .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
            
        }
        .overlay {
            VStack{
                if(viewModel.annotations != [] && viewModel.annotations  != nil) {
                    
                    ForEach(Array((viewModel.annotations.enumerated())!), id: \.offset) { index, annotation in
                        
                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                            .position(x: 100, y: 100)
                        //.position(x: CGFloat(annotation.coordinateX), y: CGFloat(annotation.coordinateY))
                            .onTapGesture {
                                currentAnnotationSelected = SelectedAnnotationModel(index: index, details: annotation)
                                self.showSheet = true
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

It's giving me 2 issues though - 1. The markers are not showing where I clicked and 2. I need the android and iOS versions to both show the markers correctly for the same image on any device, so I'm not sure how to do those same calculations in swift? - Android Version

Have you tried to use a ZStack instead? Also the GeometryReader can help you figure out where the tap was made @730wavy

Please review the answers received and comment accordingly or mark as solution if it provided insight into your issue.

The calculations are not really complicated. If the image is to be zoomed and pan, you just need to factor in the zoom/scale.
What does matter very much is the order of the modifiers, which can throw everything out of whack very easily if not placed in the right order, causing markers to not resize correctly when zoomed or not panned correctly when the image is dragged.
Here's an example where you can tap on an image to place markers. Tapping the same marker again selects it. You can add any other logic you want to the selection action.
You can pinch to zoom the image and then drag it around, the markers will resize accordingly.
The comments in the code should explain the various parts, let me know if you have any questions.
import SwiftUI

//Main view
struct ImageMarkersDemo: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZoomableImageWithMarkers(image: Image(systemName: "ladybug")) // <- Use your own image here
    }
}

//Zoomable Image With Markers View
struct ZoomableImageWithMarkers: View {
    
    //Parameters
    let image: Image
    
    //State values
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0 // Zoom level
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero // Pan offset
    @State private var markers: [ImageMarker] = []
    @State private var selectedMarker: ImageMarker?
    
    //Gesture states
    @GestureState private var magnifyBy = 1.0
    @GestureState private var drag: CGSize = .zero
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            //Helper values
            let combinedScale = scale * magnifyBy
            let adjustedScale = 1 / (1 + (combinedScale - 1) / 2) //Scales circles inversely with the scale
            
            // The base image
            image
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .padding()
                .foregroundStyle(.indigo)
            
                // Overlay markers
                .overlay {
                    ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                        ForEach(markers) { marker in
                            
                            let isSelected = selectedMarker == marker ? true : false
                            
                            Button {
                                //Select on tap
                                selectedMarker = marker
                            }
                            label: {
                                //Marker
                                Circle() // <- Customize marker here
                                    .fill(isSelected ? Color.green : Color.red)
                                    .frame(width: (isSelected ? 15 : 10) * adjustedScale) // Adjust frame size
                                    .padding(5)
                                    .position(CGPoint(
                                        x: marker.position.x,
                                        y: marker.position.y
                                    )) // Position markers relative to image
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        }
                    }
                    .animation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 3, damping: 1), value: magnifyBy)
                }
            
                //Tap gesture
                .onTapGesture(count: 1) { location in
                    markers.append( ImageMarker(position: location ) )
                }
                .offset(x: offset.width + drag.width, y: offset.height + drag.height) // Apply panning offset
            
                //Drag and magnify gestures
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .updating($drag) { value, state, _ in
                            state.width = value.translation.width
                            state.height = value.translation.height
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            // Update offset and apply flick animation
                            let velocity = CGSize(
                                width: value.predictedEndTranslation.width - value.translation.width,
                                height: value.predictedEndTranslation.height - value.translation.height
                            )
                            
                            // Update the offset for the drag
                            offset.width += value.translation.width
                            offset.height += value.translation.height
                            
                            // Animate the flick
                            withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 2, blendDuration: 0.5)) {
                                offset.width += velocity.width * 0.5 // Control flick distance
                                offset.height += velocity.height * 0.5
                            }
                        }
                        .simultaneously(with:   MagnificationGesture()
                            .updating($magnifyBy) { value, state, _ in
                                state = value
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                scale *= value
                            })
                )
                .scaleEffect(combinedScale, anchor: .center) // Apply zoom
            
            
            //Reset
            Group {
                HStack {
                    
                    //Undo button
                    Button {
                        withAnimation(.spring) {
                            if !markers.isEmpty {
                                markers.removeLast()
                            }
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.uturn.backward")
                    }
                    .disabled(markers.isEmpty)
                    
                    //Divider
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.blue.opacity(0.2))
                        .frame(width: 1)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    
                    //Reset scale
                    Button {
                        withAnimation(.spring) {
                            scale = 1
                            offset = .zero
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.up.left.and.down.right.magnifyingglass")
                    }
                    .disabled(scale == 1.0)
                    
                    //Divider
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.blue.opacity(0.2))
                        .frame(width: 1)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    
                    //Reset markers
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            markers.removeAll()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.circlepath")
                    }
                    .disabled(markers.isEmpty)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                .background(.thinMaterial, in: Capsule())
                .frame(height: 40)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
        }
    }
    
}

//Marker struct
struct ImageMarker: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    var position: CGPoint
    var label: String = ""
}

//Preview
#Preview {
    ImageMarkersDemo()
}




In SwiftUI, the image may be scaled to fit within a Image view, and its displayed size might not match the original size. Also note SwiftUI positions elements relative to their parent view. The markers are placed relative to the scaled image size.
Adding ZStack to image or adjusting scaling factor should help.
try resizable() and scaledToFit()

try this
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct ImageView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = viewModel()
    @State var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State var currentAnnotationSelected: SelectedAnnotationModel?
    @State var localX: CGFloat = 0
    @State var localY: CGFloat = 0
    @State var imageSize: CGSize = .zero // To store the size of the image
    @State var annotations: [AnnotationModel] = [] // To store all annotations
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack {
                    KFImage.url(URL(string: viewModel.uri ?? ""))
                        .placeholder { ProgressView() }
                        .loadDiskFileSynchronously()
                        .cacheMemoryOnly()


sorry but I don't understand, I think maybe your code was cut off.
